# Problema em Criar um menu responsivo

Tags: javascript, html, css

Galera estou tentando criar um menu responsivo mas estou com grandes problemas... Segue o codigo

Preciso que fique com aquele hamburguer e que quando chegue em determinado width, apareça esse icone clicando nele apareça as opçoes do menu.

```
                <!DOCTYPE html>
                <html>
                    <head>
                        <meta charset="utf-8">
                        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
                        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
                        <title>dsadsadsa/dsadsadsadsa</title>
                        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald" rel="stylesheet">
                        <meta name="description" content="FabMáquinas realiza conserto, manuteção e instalação de máquinas de lavar,Ar Condicionados e refrigeradores.">
                        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
                        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">
                        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab" rel="stylesheet">
                        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
                        <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

                    </head>
                    <body>
                        <section class="superinfo-bg">
                            <div class="texto-superinfo">
                            <h2>Segunda a Sexta - 08:00 ás 18:00 | Segunda a Sabado - 08:00 as 12:00</h2>
                            <a href="tel:1121688500"><h2>(11) 21688500</h2></a>
                            <h3>Solicite um Orçamento Grátis!</h3>
                        </div>
                        </section>
                        <nav>

                                <a href="index.html" class="logo">
                                    <img src="images/logo1.png">
                                </a>

                                <ul class="main-nav-links">
                                        <li><a href="#0">Inicio</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#0">Serviços<i class="fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                                        <ul class="nav-dropdown">
                                            <li class="nav-dropdown">
                                                    <li><a href="#0">► Conserto de Máquina de Lavar</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#0">► Conserto de Máquina de Lavar</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#0">► Conserto de Máquina de Lavar</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#0">► Conserto de Máquina de Lavar</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#0">► Conserto de Máquina de Lavar</a></li>
                                                    <li><a href="#0">► Conserto de Máquina de Lavar</a></li>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#0">Sobre</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#0">Contato</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </nav>
                    </body>
                </html>
```

css

```
                    html,
                    body {
                    height: 100%;
                    }

                    * {
                    margin: 0;
                    padding: 0;
                    box-sizing: border-box;
                    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
                    font-style: bold;
                    }
                    /* PADRAO PARA OS ELEMENTOS DA PÁGINAS */

                    a {
                    text-decoration: none;
                    }

                    ul {
                        list-style: none;
                    }

                    /* PADRAO 2 */


                    .superinfo-bg {
                            background-color: #1976D2;
                            width: 100%;
                            display: flex;
                            padding: 0.3%;
                            justify-content: center;
                    }

                    .texto-superinfo {
                        width: 100%;
                        display: flex;
                        justify-content: center;
                    }

                    .texto-superinfo h2 {
                        padding-right:40px;
                        font-size: 19px;
                    }

                    .texto-superinfo a {
                        color:#000;
                    }

                    .texto-superinfo a:hover {
                        color:white;
                    }

                    .text-superinfo h3 {
                        padding-right:40px;
                        font-size: 19px;
                    }

                    nav {
                        background: #bdbdbd;
                        display: flex;
                        justify-content: space-around;
                    }
                    nav ul a {
                        background: #bdbdbd;
                        display:block;
                    }

                    nav ul a:hover {
                        background:#A6A6A6;
                        border-bottom: 4px solid black;
                    }

                    nav > ul ul {
                        position: absolute;
                        visibility: hidden;
                    }

                    nav > ul {
                        display: flex;
                        justify-content: center;
                        align-items: center;
                    }

                    nav ul li:hover > ul {
                        visibility: visible;
                    } 

                    nav ul ul li {
                        position: relative;
                    }

                    nav ul ul ul {
                        position: absolute;
                        top: 0;
                        left: 100%;
                    }

                    nav ul li a {
                        color: #fff;
                        text-decoration: none;
                        text-transform: uppercase;
                        display: inline-block;
                        padding-top: 30px;
                        padding-bottom: 30px;
                        padding-right: 35px;
                        text-align: center;
                        padding-left: 35px;
                    }

                    .logo {
                        padding: 10px;
                    }

                    .logo img {
                        width: 300px;
                    }





























                    /* MEDIA QUEREIS */ 

                    @media(max-width:761px){
                        .texto-superinfo h2:nth-child(1) {
                                padding-right: 10px;
                        }

                        .texto-superinfo a  {
                            padding-right:15px;
                        }
                        .texto-superinfo h2:nth-child(2) {
                            padding-right: 10px;
                    }
                    }

                    @media(max-width:500px) {
                        .texto-superinfo {
                            display: flex;
                            flex-direction: column;
                            text-align: center;
                        }
                        .texto-superinfo h2 {
                            padding-top:8px;
                            padding-bottom: 8px;
                        }
                        .texto-superinfo h3 {
                            padding-bottom: 8px;
                            padding-top: 8px;
                        }
                    }
```

js

```
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    jQuery(function($){
                        $('.menu-btn' ).click(function(){
                            $('.responsive-menu').addClass('expand')
                            $('.menu-btn').addClass('btn-none')
                        })

                        $('.close-btn').click(function(){
                            $('.responsive-menu').removeClass('expand')
                            $('.menu-btn').removeClass('btn-none')
                        })

                    })

                    jQuery(function($){
                            $( '.menu-btn' ).click(function(){
                            $('.responsive-menu').toggleClass('expand')
                            })
                        })
                </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Não sou a melhor pessoa para responder isso, mas vou tentar contribuir:

Você pode criar um Intervalo que vai atualizar a cada X tempo e vai checar o tamanho da tela, quando o **width** chegar a tal valor, o "Hambúrguer" irá aparecer (`.show()`) e o menu irá sumir (`.hide()`) e quando a tela estiver maior do que aquele **width** o inverso acontecerá.

```
setInterval(function () {
    if(window.innerWidth <= 993){
        $("#botão").show(); //Botão aparece
        $("#Menu").hide(); //Menu some
    } else {
        $("#botão").hide(); //Botão some
        $("#Menu").show(); //Menu aparece
    }
},100);
```

Esse é um código meia-boca, mas acho que já deve te ajudar a implementar no seu projeto.